# p4 cmd line client on OSX always throughs error when I try to get it to do something... p4v works fine

Tags: objective-c, command-line, macos, perforce

> link-mbp:~ benb$ p4 Perforce client
>   error:  Connect to server failed;
>   check $P4PORT.  TCP connect to 1666
>   failed.  connect: 1666: Connection
>   refused link-mbp:~ benb$

though when I check p4 set it shows all the right data for those environment variables.

thoughts?

Comment: Please could you post your output with the newlines preserved - as you've currently got it, it's rather hard to read.
Also please could you post your `p4 set` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that setting my P4PORT=myserver:port solved the problem...
I thought P4HOST was going to take care of that but ... I guess I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your security level perforce may not read environmental settings.  Try specifying the P4PORT explicitly in the command

```
p4 -p host:port <command>
```